# Getting info from a data base

Tags: java, android

I have set up okHttp so that `response.body().string();` returns

```
[{"id":"1","username":"netsgets","password":"test","likedOne":"","likedTwo":"","likedThree":"","likedFour":"","likedFive":""},{"id":"2","username":"test","password":"test","likedOne":"","likedTwo":"","likedThree":"","likedFour":"","likedFive":""},{"id":"3","username":"netsgets2","password":"test","likedOne":"","likedTwo":"","likedThree":"","likedFour":"","likedFive":""}]
```

I want to search for all the usernames and add them to a HashMap. This is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
final String TestVar = response.body().string();

                                for (int data_i = 0; data_i < TestVar.length(); data_i++) {
                                    Log.d("OkHttp","debug3");
                                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


                                    try {
                                        hashMap.put("username",
                                                TestVar.getString("username"));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    usersInfo.add(hashMap);




                                }
                            }
```

Not only does it not work, The `TestVar.getString("username")` gets an error. Please help.

Comment: Hey Ron did you check my answer? does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your response is `JSONArray` so you need to parse JSON and get the object.
To get object from JSON you try below code

```
try {
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String TestVar = response.body().string();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(TestVar);
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        hashMap.put("username", jsonObject.getString("username"));
    }
}catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: YA this works but I have to click to load it exit, and click again for it to show up.... Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try{

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
    for (int data_i = 0; data_i < jsonArray.length(); data_i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(data_i);
        hashMap.put("username",jsonObject.getString("username"));
        usersInfo.add(hashMap);
    }
}catch(JSONExceptrion e){
}
```